# How to show Link/DIV on hover with moving up the upper div?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, show

I'm trying to build a Team section on a Website. I have a Div with an Image and Name of the Person. When I hover over the name, I would like to have a link to appear on its place and move the Name upwards.
Something like this (TEAM Section):
https://www.templatemonster.com/de/demo/55809.html

I tried using a solution I found here and modifying it, but it doesnt really work like I want it to:

```
#stuff {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#hover {
    width:80px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:green;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
#hover:hover {
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
#stuff:hover {

    opacity: 1.0;
}



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<section>

    <div id="hover">Hover</div>
<div id="stuff">stuff</div>
```

Is there a simple solution with CSS and/or Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

I made an example using just css.

```css
section {
  margin:5px auto; 
}

.hover-div {
  color:#FFF;
  width:200px;
}

.hover-div .stuff {
  background-color:#F00;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:0;
  position:relative;
  width:100%; 
  z-index:2;

  -webkit-transition:margin-top 0.3s;
      transition:margin-top 0.3s;
}

.hover-div .stuff-hidden {
  background-color:#00F;
  height:0;
  width:100%;

  -webkit-transition:height 0.3s;
      transition:height 0.3s; 
}

.hover-div:hover .stuff {
  margin-top:-40px;
}

.hover-div:hover .stuff-hidden {
  height:40px;
}

.image {
  background-color:#0F0;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="image">image</div> 
 <div class="hover-div">
        <div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
        <div class="stuff-hidden">Hidden stuff</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank You very much! That's exactly what I was looking for! Now my only Problem is that the red Background hides behind the Image and I don't know how to bring it to the front. I tried to solve it with overflow and z-index but it doesn't work...

Comment: If you need to use the "z-index", it's necessary to change the property "position" to "relative" to work. Check the answer, i edited it.

Comment: Thank You very much! You helped me a lot!